# Regret after declining a postdoc offer over another one

Tags: postdocs, job

I have accepted a postdoc offer, then an other offer came out and I declined it mostly because I already accepted the first one. After taking time to think and consider multiple factors I have some regrets.
Is it normal to ask if that position has been filled yet and if not is it okay to take it?

Comment: Regret, at least, is pretty common.

Answer (score 3):

Proceed with caution here. Regret is common and, as we say "The grass is always greener on the other side of the fence".

I can't really recommend one way or the other, since it is both your decision and you who will benefit or suffer from any decision you make. But I suggest you consider the following.

You leave yourself at risk of seeming unreliable to both institutions if you try to make a change after you have accepted an offer. That wouldn't serve you well if it were to occur.

Personally, I would only be tempted to try to switch if there were something decidedly negative about the accepted offer/position. I would be more inclined to write the second institution, thanking them, telling them that you just recently accepted another offer *before this one was made* and that perhaps the future will offer possibilities for joining them.

But, consider that there might be risk in trying for a short term optimization here. Think about the longer term.

Answer (score 0):

Reget is common in our life; I would suggest discussing with the Professor again if it's not filled he/she might offer you. If they don't offer, you will not regret in future that you did not ask.

Comment: That leaves open the question of declining the accepted offer. That might be problematic.

Comment: @Buffy Yes, it is better to quit in the beginning rather than declining the performance, At the end only performance matters.